# How to quickly compare every element of an ndarray with every element of a sorted list/array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I have an `ndarray` A(an image in 2D for example) for which values are integers going from 0 to N.

I have another list B or array containing a list of numbers that are in the range of 0 to N.

I want to compare the first array to every element of the second list in order to obtain a new `ndarray` indicating if the value of the `pixel` is in the list.

A is around 10000 * 10000

B is a list having 10000-100000 values.

N goes up to 500 000

Here is an example of the results I wish to obtain.

I already tried for loops, it works but it's really slow as I have really big matrices. I also tried to do it with `.any()` and `numpy's` compare function but did not managed to obtain the desired result.

```
a = np.array([2, 23, 15, 0, 7, 5, 3])
b = np.array([3,7,17])
c = np.array([False, False, False, False, True, False, True])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape the array `a` to have an extra dimension which will be used for comparing with `b` and then use `np.any` along that dimension:

```
>>> np.any(a[..., None] == b, axis=-1)
array([False, False, False, False,  True, False,  True])
```

This approach is flexible since it works with other element-wise comparison functions too. For example for two float arrays, instead of `np.equal` we typically want to compare [`np.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) and we can do so by simply exchanging the comparison function:

```
>>> np.any(np.isclose(a[..., None], b), axis=-1)
```

If equality is however the criterion then `np.isin` will perform better since it doesn't need to go through an intermediate broadcasted array of shape `a.shape + (b.size,)` which will be reduced along the last axis anyway. That means it saves both in memory and compute since it doesn't need to allocate that array and neither perform all the computations:

```
In [2]: a = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 100))

In [3]: b = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=1000)

In [4]: %timeit np.any(a[..., None] == b, axis=-1)
12.1 ms ± 48.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit np.isin(a, b)
608 µs ± 4.27 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try it too.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html#numpy.in1d):

```
>>> np.in1d(a, b)
array([False, False, False, False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

There's also [`numpy.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html#numpy-isin), which is recommended for new code.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it, it works properly for a 1D array (A), but when I try it on my real case, my A can be more than 1D (2D (grayscale image),3D(color image), and more). In this case, the output is still 1 dimensional. Will a simple reshape give me the desired result?

Comment: @user11823711: `np.isin` works out of the box with multidimensional arrays.  Can  you use that?

Comment: Yes it does work nicely and doesn't need the reshape, I didn't knew this function and I didn't found it with my research. Thank you again.